# What are the methods to collect data for building machine translation model (French to German)

Tags: python, neural-network, recurrent-neural-network, machine-translation

I have a lot of emails in french language and I want to convert it into German language.

Now for the same I need Machine Translation Model, but not sure how to collect data for creating the model.

It's ok to have a low accuracy in the starting but I am not finding a way to start collecting data.

Anyone please suggest...

Answer (score 0):

> German-French texts extracted from the website of the Federal Foreign Office Berlin. This includes 11,852 pairs that were translated between October 2013 and the beginning of November 2015 and converted into a .TMX file format.

https://data.europa.eu/euodp/en/data/dataset/elrc_42